# Em python como eu faço a leitura de dados digitados na mesma linha e atribui as variaveis

Tags: python

Preciso realizar a leitura de 3 dados digitados na mesma linha e inserir em três variáveis diferentes utilizado o python.

Comment: a = "1 2 3"

b, c, d = a.split(' ')

print(b)